# Have I fried port my A2?

Tags: arduino

I'm playing around with a SparkFun Redboard (essentially, an Arduino UNO).

I have a simple 5V sensor that I'd been trying to get to work with A2 and analogRead(). Nothing seemed to work.  It's supposed to be cycling from 0 to 5V, which should give me values from 0 to 1023, and I'd get constant values of around 260.

In desperation, I tried using other ports.  On A0, A1, and A3 I get the signals I expect. On A2, still nada.

So, the question.  Is there something I could have done in configuring things that would have made A2 and only A2 stop reading correctly?  If so, how can I reset it?

Or is there some other function that I might be using that could interfere with A2?  Currently, I'm only using Serial over USB - could that interfere with A2?

Or could I simply have fried the port?

Comment: This might get a better answer at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATmega 328 has just 1 analog to digital converter (ADC) so you might think the analog inputs are all or nothing.  Between the chip input pins and the ADC is an 8 channel multiplexer that connects one of the analog input pins to the ADC.  So if you damage the mux, you could have the symptom you see where only one input is not functional.

The value stuck at 260 makes me think there is a chance. Before tossing the chip, make sure you are not:

- setting pull up resistors on the pin - that would have unwanted effect
- writing to the pin - you can still write to a output pin at same time trying to read as analog input.  Nothing good will happen, but you can do it.

Run a stripped down program that does nothing but read one analog input, and have nothing connected to the chip.  If you still see 260, the input is likely toast.

Comment: I wrote a simple program that used all six analog pins as digital outputs, and wired up an LED. All of the pins except A2 would blink the LED. So yes, it is fried.  Thanks.